# how to stop looping when the statement meet criteria? -vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Year             As Long
Dim i As Long

Year = 2008
For Year = 2008 To ComboBox2.Value
    For i = 2 To 200 Step 12
        If ComboBox1.Value = "Januari" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Februari" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Maret" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "April" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 3, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Mei" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 4, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Juni" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 5, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Juli" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 6, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Agustus" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 7, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "September" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 8, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Oktober" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 9, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "November" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 10, 1).Value
         ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Desember" Then
            Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(i + 12, 1).Value
         End If
    Next i

Next Year

Sheets(2).Range("I5").Value = ("CONTRACT SPOT")

End Sub
```

i want it when i pick januari 2009 combination it show 1,i pick januari 2010 combination it show 13 and so on. please help

Comment: so far it only show last number when the loop is over, for example, when i pick januari 2009 it show 193

Comment: combobox2.value range is 2008 to 2050

Comment: if you want to exit the `For` loop when criteria is met, then put inside the `If` the `Exit For` statement. What exactly are you trying to do with your code, if you explained better, maybe there is a way to optimize your code

Comment: exit for is not working, i am trying to get a value from another sheet with combination of two combobox, first combobox is a list of month and another one is list of year. every month and year combination there is a value that i want to put in cell g5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ComboBox1.Value has the month and ComboBox2.Value has the year.

And you want to count
1 = January, 2009
2 = February, 2009
...
13 = January, 2010

Then you need to do some math

```
Dim iMonth as Integer

Dim iYear as Integer
iYear = ComboBox2.Value

Select Case  ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Januari"
        iMonth = 1
    Case "Februari"
        iMonth = 2
    Case "Maret"
        iMonth = 3
    Case "April"
        iMonth = 4
    Case "Mei"
        iMonth = 5
    Case "Juni"
        iMonth = 6
    Case "Juli"
        iMonth = 7
    Case "Agustus"
        iMonth = 8
    Case "September"
        iMonth = 9
    Case "Oktober"
        iMonth = 10
    Case "November"
        iMonth = 11
    Case "Desember"
        iMonth = 12
End Select

Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(iMonth + ((iYear - 2009) * 12), 1).Value
```

I just coded this on the fly, it may have some errors, let me know if it works! :)

Comment: i want it to take a value from another sheet, january 2009 = 1, "1" is just a dummy number i create to make it easier.

Comment: It is not clear what you try to say. So data from January 2009 is stored in sheet 1, February 2009 is stored in sheet 2  and so on?

Comment: no, all the combination of month and year data is store t sheet 3

Comment: Oh ok. So use the the code I published above and change the last line to the following Range("G15").Value = Sheets(3).Cells(iMonth + ((iYear - 2009) * 12), 1).Value

Comment: It is hard to code without knowing the layout of Sheets(3) data. I believe you may have to add an offest depending on the starting row. In this case, for January 2009 it will take row 1 col 1 value from Sheet(3), for January 2010 it will take row 13 col 1 value from Sheets(3) and so on